# I do not know why FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Tags: java, android

```
>     private class RssFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
>       String response = "";
>     
>       @Override
>       protected void onPreExecute() {
>           // TODO: Dialog
>       }
>     
>       @Override
>       protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
>           try {
>               String feed = "http://google.com";
>               HtmListParser rh = new HtmListParser();
>               rssStr = rh.getLatestArticles(feed);
>           } catch (Exception e) {
>               Log.e("error_connection", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
>           }
>           return response;
>     
>       }
>     
>       @Override
>       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
>           // TODO: dismiss Dialog and set adapter
>       }
>     }



>     public class HtmListParser {
>       private RssFeedStructure feedStr = new RssFeedStructure();
>       private List<RssFeedStructure> rssList = new ArrayList<RssFeedStructure>();
>     
>     
>       public List<RssFeedStructure> getLatestArticles(String feedUrl) {
>            try {                                              
>              Document doc = Jsoup.connect(feedUrl).get();
>              
>             } catch (IOException e) {
>                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>            
>     
>           return null;
>       }
>     
>     }


**and The Exceptions:**
```

> ```
> 02-07 08:40:47.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1027): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
> 02-07 08:40:47.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1027): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
> ```
>
> doInBackground()
>       02-07 08:40:47.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1027):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
>       02-07 08:40:47.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1027):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
>       02-07 08:40:47.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1027):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
>       02-07 08:40:47.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1027):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
>       02-07 08:40:47.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1027):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>       02-07 08:40:47.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1027):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>       02-07 08:40:47.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1027):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>       02-07 08:40:47.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1027):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>       02-07 08:40:47.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1027): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup
>       02-07 08:40:47.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1027):   at com.newsinlevels.helper.HtmListParser.getLatestArticles(HtmListParser.java:20)
>       02-07 08:40:47.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1027):   at com.newsinlevels.activity.MainActivity$RssFeedTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:120)
>       02-07 08:40:47.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1027):   at com.newsinlevels.activity.MainActivity$RssFeedTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
>       02-07 08:40:47.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1027):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>       02-07 08:40:47.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1027):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
>       02-07 08:40:47.346: E/AndroidRuntime(1027):   ... 4 more

Comment: make sure u have added Jsoup jar in `libs` folder in project

Comment: I think, problem is maybe with Jsoup class.

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K, Thank you, problem was with adding Jsoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android runtime environment cannot find the JSoup class in class path when executing.
You need to ensure that the JSoup library is included in the package deployed to the android.